# sympy produces non-orthogonal column space

Tags: python, sympy, linear-algebra

When calculating the column space of a matrix with irrational numbers (e.g., `sqrt(3)`), `sympy.columnspace()` produces two vectors that are *not* orthogonal (e.g., `V_1^TV_2 != 0`).

Given the matrix A:

```
A = Matrix([[1.25000000000000, 0.25*sqrt(3), 0.500000000000000, 0, 1.25000000000000,  -0.25*sqrt(3)], [0.25*sqrt(3), 0.750000000000000, -0.5*sqrt(3), 0, 0.25*sqrt(3), -0.750000000000000], [0.500000000000000, -0.5*sqrt(3), 2, 0, 0.500000000000000, 0.5*sqrt(3)], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1.25000000000000, 0.25*sqrt(3), 0.500000000000000, 0, 1.25000000000000, -0.25*sqrt(3)], [-0.25*sqrt(3), -0.750000000000000, 0.5*sqrt(3), 0, -0.25*sqrt(3), 0.750000000000000]])
```

Sympy calculates the columnspace to be:

```
V = A.columnspace()

V = [Matrix([
[         1.25],
[ 0.25*sqrt(3)],
[          0.5],
[            0],
[         1.25],
[-0.25*sqrt(3)]]), Matrix([
[0.25*sqrt(3)],
[        0.75],
[-0.5*sqrt(3)],
[           0],
[0.25*sqrt(3)],
[       -0.75]])]
```

But, the dot product of the two vectors that form the column space is non-zero:

```
B = V[0].dot(V[1])

B = 0.75*sqrt(3)
```

Why is the resulting column space non-orthogonal? I have tried to simplify the above expression to remove the decimals (and potential roundoff errors), but to no avail.

Comment: Why should they be orthogonal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vectors that comprise the column space are not necessarily orthogonal. In the above example, the column space is simply the first two columns of the matrix.

To orthogonalize, use the Gram-Schmidt process:

```
V = GramSchmidt(A.columnspace(),True)
```

where the optional argument `True` corresponds to normalizing the resulting vectors.